# How can you use firebase analytics to know which user recieved notification in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

How can you use firebase analytics to know which user recieved notification in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is a way to **develop** apps for many platform, but the apps end up running on platforms like iOS and Android. So notifications are delivered with the normal mechanisms for iOS, Android, and Web.

To learn how to troubleshoot message delivery to those platforms, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [understanding message delivery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery), which explains the reports in the Firebase console, the aggregated data you can get via the Firebase API, and the option to get detailed delivery data by connecting to BigQuery.